# Add numbers to bibliography - Latex

Tags: latex, bibliography

I have the problem with numbering references in my doc. Here's my preambule before `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass[polish]{article}

%\newcommand{\DoNotLoadEpstopdf}{}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse,eqparbox,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{subfig}


%-------Definition of \signature--
 \def\signature#1#2#3{{\hskip#1in{\hbox to #2in%
{\leaders\hbox to .00625in{\hfil.\hfil}\hfill}}%
 \par\hskip#1in#3\vskip1cm}}
%------------------------------
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
    \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ts}{\quad}

%-------Big chapter letters--
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\huge\headingfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
%------------------------------

\frenchspacing

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
```

Now when I try to create my bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem{1939}
N. Bohr, J. Wheeler, \textit{Phys. Rev.}, \textbf{56} (1939) 426.
\bibitem{parametryzacje}
R. W. Hasse, W. D. Myers, \textit{Geometrical Relationships of Macroscopic Nuclear Physics}, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1988. 
\bibitem{MFH}
K. Pomorski and J. Bartel, \textit{IJMPE} Vol. \textbf{15} No. 2, 417 (2006).
\bibitem{Krappe}
H. J. Krappe, J. R. Nix, A. J. Sierk, \textit{Phys. Rev. C} \textbf{20}, 922 (1979).
\bibitem{Moll1}
P. M{\"o}ller, J. R. Nix, \textit{Nucl. Phys. A} \textbf{361}, 117 (1981).
\bibitem{Moll2}
P. M{\"o}ller, J. R. Nix, W. D. Myers, W. J. Świątecki, \textit{At. Data and Nucl. Data Tables} \textbf{59}, 185 (1995).
\bibitem{Muntian}
I. Muntian, Z. Patyk, A. Sobiczewski, \textit{Acta Phys. Pol. B} \textbf{32}, 691 (2001).
\bibitem{Pomorski}
Bożena Nerlo-Pomorska, Krzysztof Pomorski, \textit{Zarys teorii jądra atomowego}, PWN, Warszawa, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I'm getting this errors and no numbers in my bibliography:

```
linia 553: Paragraph ended before \list was complete.
linia 553: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
linia 553: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
linia 553: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
linia 554: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{1939}
linia 556: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{parametryzacje}
linia 558: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{MFH}
linia 560: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{Krappe}
linia 562: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{Moll1}
linia 564: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{Moll2}
linia 566: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{Muntian}
linia 568: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem{Pomorski}
: No style for language 'polish'.
linia 554: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 556: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 558: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 560: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 562: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 564: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 566: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
linia 568: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

I tried to use `\bibliographystyle{stylename}` but it does not work. I have no ideas how to get the numbers.
Have you got any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed one thing after: `\begin{thebibliography}` you have to define the width, e.g. `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`, for more details see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198330/argument-in-thebibliography

Comment: I missed that. I tried with names like `abbrv` or `acm` in brackets, not with numbers. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: But please @Stefan, I have to get bibitem name in text. Now I'm getting only number of reference in my text. For ex. if I use `\cite{parametryzacje}` in my doc, I want to get `parametryzacje [2]`, not only `[2]`.

Comment: your `bibitem` should be changed accordingly, try to write \bibitem[parametryzacje]{parametryzacje}. This would allow getting you defined name in place you are citing `[parametryzacje]`. But getting "parametryzacje [2]" might a little bit non-intuitive. Well, you can remove [] from the default style and somehow incorporate it with the names, but before please think how multiple citing should look like.